# Using sub-query find the average salary of employees for each department , order employees within a department by age

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

**Table Employee**

```
Name    Age Department      Salary
Ramesh  20  Finance         50,000
Deep    25  Sales           30,000
Suresh  22  Finance         50,000
Ram     28  Finance         20,000
Pradeep 22  Sales           20,000
```

How to solve using sub-query?

Using window function,

```
select name,age,department,salary.
avg(salary) OVER(partition by department order by age) AS avg_salary from Employee
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Name    Age Department  Salary  Avg_Salary
Ramesh  20  Finance        50,000     40, 000
Suresh  22  Finance        50,000     40, 000
Ram     28  Finance        20,000     40, 000
Pradeep 22  Sales          20,000     25, 000
Deep    25  Sales          30,000     25, 000
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
select e.Name,
       e.Age,
       e.Department,
       e.Salary,
       tbl.avg_salary
from employees e
inner join ( select Department,
                    avg(Salary) as avg_salary 
             from employees
             group by Department
           ) as tbl on e.Department=tbl.Department
order by e.Department,e.Age asc;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/IYBkuzw-

Comment: Thanks man got it. One thing to ask could you please check the query using window function above. The output seems different using the window function.

Comment: @BiswajitPatnaik just remove the order by age part https://dbfiddle.uk/9U0XSS6K

Comment: hi it worked just to ask why there is difference if we include order by